# I need a pull some data from Active Directory. I want a list of all the users in AD whose last name field has "PA" after their last name

Tags: powershell

Use PowerShell to pull all users from AD that has "PA" in the last name field.

```
Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.SurName -Like "*PA*" -And $_.DisplayName -Like "*PA*"} | Select Name, SamAccountName | FT

Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.SurName -Like "*PA*" -And $_.DisplayName -Like "*PA*"} | Select Name, SamAccountName | FT
```

It is pulling the names of all the user sin AD whose last name has the value of "PA" for example: "Palmer" or "Joppa". That is not what ia m looking for. This is what i want. Say a user first name a John and last name is Cooper. But then when the account was created in AD, the last name is listed as "Cooper PA". So the "PA" is after the last name with a space between and last name and the "PA".

Comment: I guess you just need to remove the tailing asterisks in the like pattern: `$.SurName -Like "*PA"`

Comment: Change the filter to `-Like "* PA"` (with a space before the `P` and no trailing asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADuser -Filter 'surname -like "* pa"'
```

EDIT:  You should frame a question clearly, and give a coding attempt.  But this is interesting:

```
get-aduser -filter * | group-object { "$($_.givenname) $($_.surname)" }

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
2     Joseph Smith              {CN=jsmith,OU=People,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com, CN=jsmith2...
```

Comment: Ken, I could not be more happier with your help. That works perfectly and did exactly what I wanted. But I need help with one more thing if you or someone could help. Not sure if it's possible to query all Users in AD that have the same first and last name. Example: Get a list of all users whose firstname and lastname are exactly the same. eg. Then get the SamAccountName of those users. I can't quite figure out how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Who's Ken?  Can you give my post the green checkmark?  I think this is the only way to compare 2 properties.  `get-aduser -filter * | where { $_.givenname -eq $_.surname -and $_.givenname } | select -first 1`  At least in this example, the pipe gets killed after the first match.  That would make a good new question.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to find all the users with the same first name and the same last name. For example: List all the "John Smith" or all the "Mary Jane" or list all the "Dan White".